# Не могу понять почему не проверяется email

Tags: php, pdo

То что сделал я...

```
function RegistrationUser () {
  $date_registration = date("d.m.Y");

  $sql_ver = $this->db->prepare("select login, email from users where login = :login and email = :email");
  $sql_ver->execute(array('login' => $this->newParamArray[5], 'email' => $this->newParamArray[2]));

  $sql_ver->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $user_date = $sql_ver->fetch();

  if ($user_date['login'] == $this->newParamArray[5]){
    echo"Такой login уже есть в системе";
  } else {
    if ($user_date['email'] == $this->newParamArray[2]) {
      echo"Такой email уже есть в системе";
    } else {
      $sql_registration = $this->db->prepare("insert users (name, lastname, login, email, sex, birthday, pass, main_photo, status, lang, data_registr) value ( :name, :lastname, :login, :email, :sex, :birthday, :pass, :main_photo, :status, :lang, :data_registr )");
      $sql_registration->execute(array(
              'name' => $this->newParamArray[0],
              'lastname' => $this->newParamArray[1],
              'login' => $this->newParamArray[5],
              'email' => $this->newParamArray[2],
              'sex' => $this->newParamArray[3],
              'birthday' => $this->newParamArray[4],
              'pass' => md5($this->newParamArray[6]),
              'main_photo' => '',
              'status' => 0,
              'lang' => substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2),
              'data_registr' => $date_registration
      ));

      if(!$sql_registration) {
        echo "Произошла ошибка, смотри файл ошибок.";
        file_put_contents('system/PDOErrors.txt', mysql_error().'<br />', FILE_APPEND);
      } else {
        $_SESSION['us_login'] = $this->newParamArray[5];
        $_SESSION['us_pass'] = $this->newParamArray[6];
        $_SESSION['us_lang'] = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        //header("Location: /index.php");
        echo "session dates: login:".$_SESSION['us_login']." pass: ".$_SESSION['us_pass']."<br />array dates: login:".$this->newParamArray[5]." pass: ".$this->newParamArray[6]."<br />base dates: email:".$user_date['email'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Проверяет только логин до почты не доходит перестает видеть массив с данными из базы, не пойму почему если они объявления ДО цикла!

Comment: Выводится какое-то сообщение об ошибке? Как определяете, что массив $user_date не виден?

Comment: Ошибок не дает, правильно из базы берет логин и почту, когда вывожу на экран через print_r массив  $user_date в первом цикле который проверяет логи, он выдает на экран и логин и почту из базы верно, когда также вывожу но в цикле ниже который проверяет посту ничего не пишет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильная логика запроса, у существующего логина может быть другая почта, а у существующей почты другой логин. Либо 2 разных запроса на выборку, либо 1ин оптимизированный.

P.S советую в запросе возвращать COUNT, и сравнивать его с 0, и limit 1.

Comment: Я тоже думал о count, но хочу показать пользователю что конкретно в базе уже есть, так удобней на много, поэтом подскажите какой 1ин оптимизированный запрос может быть?

Comment: @privetsh тогда советую так: SELECT `login`, `mail` FROM `` WHERE `login`='' OR `mail` = '' LIMIT 2
тогда проверять хотяб всего 2 записи.

Comment: Гениальное и великосердечное спасибо!!!!!!